# Tracking positions using tuples in a dictionary (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've implemented a dictionary/hashing algorithm to add the points to each team that plays (t1, t2 represents teams, p1, p2 represents their respective points per match). 3500 points are added if an away team wins, 3000 if a home team wins, 1000 if they tie, 50 if they lose. My code does just that, however, I get errors when two teams tie for first place or last place on the final leaderboard. My mentors have suggested using tuples to keep a "counter" that tracks who made it to first place or last place first, however, due to tuples not being mutable, I don't know how to approach this without increasing the runtime of my program. Any ideas?

```
import sys

def firstLast(q):

     games = {}
     for i in range(q):
        t1, t2, p1, p2 = input().strip().split(' ')
        t1, t2, p1, p2 = [t1, t2, int(p1), int(p2)]

        if t1 not in games:
            games[t1] = p1
        else:
            games[t1] += p1

        if t2 not in games:
            games[t2] = p2
        else:
            games[t2] += p2

        if p1>p2:
            games[t1]+=3000
            games[t2]+=50
        elif p1==p2:
            games[t1]+=1000
            games[t2]+=1000
        elif p1<p2:
            games[t1]+=50
            games[t2]+=3500

    #first = max(games.values())
    #last = min(games.values())
    first = max(games, key=games.get)
    last = min(games, key=games.get)

    print (first,last,sep='\n')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = int(input())
    result = firstLast(q)
```

Comment: Ordered Dict might help in this case

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: the error is it doesn't always print the team that should be in first or last if two or more teams tie for that place

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rework that prints all teams that tied for first or last instead of randomly displaying one:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def firstLast(q):

    games = defaultdict(int)

    for _ in range(q):
        t1, t2, p1, p2 = input().strip().split(' ')
        p1, p2 = int(p1), int(p2)

        games[t1] += p1
        games[t2] += p2

        if p1 > p2:
            games[t1] += 3000
            games[t2] += 50
        elif p1 < p2:
            games[t1] += 50
            games[t2] += 3500
        else:
            games[t1] += 1000
            games[t2] += 1000

    maximum = max(games.values())
    minimum = min(games.values())

    first = [key for key, value in games.items() if value == maximum]
    last = [key for key, value in games.items() if value == minimum]

    print(' '.join(first), ' '.join(last), sep='\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = int(input())
    firstLast(q)
```

However, it's not exactly what you desire.  My problem is I can't get my head around the concept of "the team that came in last place first".  Perhaps if you supplied some examples, it might help me and/or others answer your question.

Comment: Okay so let's say I have two teams, one called Rex and the other call Yankees. These teams are the ones that would come last place. Now, lets say Rex went against another team called Poles and lost the game, then after that game between Rex and Poles, Yankees play against Mets and loses the game. So in the end, Yankees would've lost a game after Rex so I'd want to return Yankees. I think I worded my original question incorrectly there...I meant to say I wanted to return the team that took first place first and the team that took last place last